# Нужно ли побитовое умножение в данном фрагменте метода resize() класса HashMap<K, V>?

Tags: java, арифметика

Речь идет о данном куске кода:

```
newTab[e.hash & (newCap - 1)] = e;
```

Мы знаем, что `capacity` `HashMap'а` всегда кратен 2. Соответственно результат выражения `newCap - 1` будет представлять в двоичном представлении набор единиц. Тогда операция побитового умножения этого результата и данного числа, которое меньше этого результата(что соблюдается для данных значений в `HashMap`), равна этому числу.
Пример:

```
(64 - 1) & 51

  111111
* 110011
  ------
  110011

110011 = 51.
```

Тогда зачем производится эта операция:

```
e.hash & (newCap - 1)
```

Если ее можно заменить на эту:

```
e.hash
```

Вот исходный код метода `resize()` для понимания контекста.

```
/**
 * Initializes or doubles table size.  If null, allocates in
 * accord with initial capacity target held in field threshold.
 * Otherwise, because we are using power-of-two expansion, the
 * elements from each bin must either stay at same index, or move
 * with a power of two offset in the new table.
 *
 * @return the table
 */
final Node<K,V>[] resize() {
    Node<K,V>[] oldTab = table;
    int oldCap = (oldTab == null) ? 0 : oldTab.length;
    int oldThr = threshold;
    int newCap, newThr = 0;
    if (oldCap > 0) {
        if (oldCap >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
            threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            return oldTab;
        }
        else if ((newCap = oldCap << 1) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY &&
                 oldCap >= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)
            newThr = oldThr << 1; // double threshold
    }
    else if (oldThr > 0) // initial capacity was placed in threshold
        newCap = oldThr;
    else {               // zero initial threshold signifies using defaults
        newCap = DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        newThr = (int)(DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR * DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }
    if (newThr == 0) {
        float ft = (float)newCap * loadFactor;
        newThr = (newCap < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY && ft < (float)MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ?
                  (int)ft : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    threshold = newThr;
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
    Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];
    table = newTab;
    if (oldTab != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < oldCap; ++j) {
            Node<K,V> e;
            if ((e = oldTab[j]) != null) {
                oldTab[j] = null;
                if (e.next == null)
                    newTab[e.hash & (newCap - 1)] = e;
                    //Эта строка!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                else if (e instanceof TreeNode)
                    ((TreeNode<K,V>)e).split(this, newTab, j, oldCap);
                else { // preserve order
                    Node<K,V> loHead = null, loTail = null;
                    Node<K,V> hiHead = null, hiTail = null;
                    Node<K,V> next;
                    do {
                        next = e.next;
                        if ((e.hash & oldCap) == 0) {
                            if (loTail == null)
                                loHead = e;
                            else
                                loTail.next = e;
                            loTail = e;
                        }
                        else {
                            if (hiTail == null)
                                hiHead = e;
                            else
                                hiTail.next = e;
                            hiTail = e;
                        }
                    } while ((e = next) != null);
                    if (loTail != null) {
                        loTail.next = null;
                        newTab[j] = loHead;
                    }
                    if (hiTail != null) {
                        hiTail.next = null;
                        newTab[j + oldCap] = hiHead;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newTab;
}
```

Comment: @extrn Очень логичное объяснение.

Comment: @extrn Перенесите в ответ - ваше предположение верно(проверил метод hash - для каждого объекта Node в конструкторе передают метод hash(или переменную, содержащую результат метода hash) и присваивают в конструкторе внутренней переменной hash. А именно от объекта Node в данном случае и берется переменная hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хеш (результат вызова `hashCode()`) вероятнее всего хранится целиком, а вот для вычисления индекса используется только его младшая часть, как в примере.

Иначе при `resize` как минимум пришлось бы повторно вычислять хеши всех элементов.